# Google Cloud App Engine Instance Class / CPU Speed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a single backend worker on Google Cloud App Engine. I have a YAML file that defines (among other things):

```
env: flex

resources:
  memory_gb: 2
  cpu: 1
  
instance_class: B8
...
```

I can control the memory size, the number of processors, but I need a faster CPU. I set `instance_class: B8`, but it doesn't help (probably works just for the Standard environment, not Flex).

Is there a way to control which instance (i.e. CPU speed) to run it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify the CPU speed. You can specify the number of cores and the RAM.

[App Engine Flexible Resource Settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings)

The Instance Type `B8` is used with App Engine Standard and not Flexible.

Review the App Engine Flexible [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing) for additional information.